# Solution for alerting users from time to time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I would like to ask for **information**, **documentation**, **method**, or **solution** for a case as follows:

1 table A, there is a lot of data. A record in table A has 2 fields: *created_time* (record creation time) and *deadline_time* (record processing time).

**How can I send a notification to the user, when the other record's due date is nearing, or processing is overdue?**

The system I have is using kafka to handle event-based messages, and send them to the user. But in the other case of static data, no other events are generated.

I was thinking of a solution that would be to use a continuous scan and send kafka if a message is near critical or out of date. But that doesn't seem very good, because to ensure load balance, I use many processes on many modules running at the same time, which will conflict with each other. Is there another solution to this problem?

Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Is a cron task does not fit your requirement? If so, why? Like run it every 5 minutes and get a list of records that should be sent?

The other solution may be remember deadline_time in memory after saving, sort them by deadline_time in queue and work with the ordered queue?

Comment: I know if i use a process that repeats for a period of time, reading data from the DB and alerting the user it can be solved, but it doesn't seem to be optimal

Comment: https://www.jobrunr.io/en/ - try to check this thing